# Vectorized str_locate not working as intended

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(string=c('abcde', 'cde'))
```

I want to find the *end* position of "de" in each string, which I can determine like so:

```
df %>% 
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(pos=str_locate(string = string, pattern = "de")[2])

##   string    pos
##    abcde      5
##      cde      3
```

This is the intended output ***but*** I don't wish to use `rowwise()` because it is very slow for large data frames.

So I tried to vectorize my function and remove the `rowwise()` command:

```
Vstr_locate <- Vectorize(str_locate)

df %>% 
 #rowwise() %>%
 mutate(pos=Vstr_locate(string = string, pattern = "de")[2])
```

But that didn't work:

```
##   string    pos
##    abcde      5
##      cde      5
```

Questions:

- Why doesn't my vectorized function work?
- How I can get the intended output without using `rowwise()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str_locate` is already vectorized, no `rowwise` or `Vectorize` needed:

```
df %>% mutate(pos=str_locate(string = string, pattern = "de")[, 2])
#   string pos
# 1  abcde   5
# 2    cde   3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a comma in the brackets

```
df %>% 
  #rowwise() %>%
  mutate(pos=Vstr_locate(string = string, pattern = "de")[2,])
  string pos
1  abcde   5
2    cde   3
```

Look at the outputs of the two functions

```
str_locate(string = "abcde", pattern = "de")
     start end
[1,]     4   5
```

vs.

```
Vstr_locate(string = "abcde", pattern = "de")
     abcde
[1,]     4
[2,]     5
```

Similarly, if you apply each over a list

```
library(purrr)
strings <- c('abcde', 'cde')
map(strings, str_locate, "de")
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     4   5

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]     2   3
```

vs.

```
map(strings, Vstr_locate, "de")
[[1]]
     abcde
[1,]     4
[2,]     5

[[2]]
     cde
[1,]   2
[2,]   3
```

The element you want is indexed as `[2,]` with `Vstr_locate`